# RoR repeated events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ice-cube

I have:

```
scaffold EventGroup name:string description:text event_quantity:integer
scaffold Event event_name:string starts_at:datetime ends_at:datetime event_group:references
```

Dependencies:

```
EventGroup has_many: events
Event belongs_to: event_group
```

How can I schedule repeating events for event_group [every friday and sunday, 4 times]? Any ideas?...

Comment: I don't understand your question. Would you please clarify? What does "set a repeating picker schedule for events" mean? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Still not clear, I'm afraid.  Do you mean you automatically want to create 8 events for an event_group object?

Comment: Ideally, only set `starts_at` rules => create X events that belong to event_group. (X=event_quantity, is set in event_group model

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iCalendar provides standards for capturing event repeat rules (see [here](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rrule.html)). There are many examples, including one similar to yours:

> Weekly on Tuesday and Thursday for 5 weeks:
>
> DTSTART;TZID=US-Eastern:19970902T090000
>   RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=19971007T000000Z;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH

or

> RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=10;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH

That's just for capturing the rule. How you capture it (what your UI looks like) and how you use it are entirely different topics.

When you say, "How can I schedule repeating events", that sounds like a much broader question.